# Google Chrome and Firefox not displaying background image from subdomain

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, background

I am trying to add a background image using CSS. I am using a site builder system webstore (epages), I can only edit the CSS.

I have to upload files to a subdomain, which I have done. The following code works in Edge, but not in Firefox or Chrome.

```
.body {
    background-size: cover;
    background: url('http://content.store-name.com/bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This, however works in all browsers. I am using a hack with a hidden product image to upload to the webstore as there is no media manager.

```
.body {
    background-size: cover;
    background: url('https://store-name.com/bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Do chrome and firefox on https sites block CSS loading files from http sites or can CSS not load from subdomains/other domains in general?

Comment: 1 is content.store-name and the other is just store-name. Is that right or is that maybe where it goes wrong?

Comment: The urls are both correct meaning if you type the address in the browser you can see the images. However content.store-name is a subdomain with http and storne-name is a tld with https. I am wondering if accessing a http subdomain from a https site is the issue.